# Cannot control click a button in Autoit scripting

Tags: script, automation, autoit

I have been trying to automate a button click using an auto IT script in an application.

The window title of the application is **EDI867 Tracer** and the button I am trying to click is ***Browse***.

The control info that I got from *Autoit Window Info* is as below

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  EDI867 TRACER
Class:  WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a
Position:   0, 0
Size:   1366, 728
Style:  0x16010000
ExStyle:    0x00050000
Handle: 0x00E606C6

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a
Instance:   5
ClassnameNN:    WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a5
Name:   btnBrowse
Advanced (Class):   [NAME:btnBrowse]
ID: 7998122
Text:   
Position:   1236, 70
Size:   93, 24
ControlClick Coords:    25, 11
Style:  0x56010000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x007A0AAA

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   1261, 81
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xE5FFF2

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
EDI867
Comparison
File
Customer :
CalComp :
Status :
EDI TRACER


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
EDI861
File
```

I am trying to control click this button. I tried all the possible `controlclick` syntax that I know using the above window info but nothing seems to automate the button click.

I am open for suggestions to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the valid handle of the window using attributes.

Also get the handle of the control by using AutoIT window info. 
The button class should be something like `CLASS:WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a` and its instance should be also given (say 5). Then script looks like:

```
Local $hSecWnd=WinGetHandle("[CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a; W:1366; H:728]")
ControlClick($hSecWnd,"","[CLASS:WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a; INSTANCE:5]")
```